# EF6 does not recognize Func lambda as filter for Where

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-6

I have the following entities:

```cs
[Table("Customer", Schema = "dbo")]
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[Table("Payment", Schema = "dbo")]
public class Payment
{
    public int PaymentId { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Period { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CustomerId")]
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to filter `Payment` table by `Period` and `Price`. Each of predicate must be in its own `Where` method. So, I get the following:

```cs
int price = 200;
var period = new DateTime(2020, 10, 3);

using var db = new TestContext();

// Option 1: anonymous lambda
var payments1 = db.Payments
                  .Where(p => p.Period < period)
                  .Where(p => p.Price <= price);

foreach (var payment in payments1)
{
    listBox.Items.Add(
        $"Payment: Payment Id={payment.PaymentId}, " +
        $"Customer Id`={payment.CustomerId}, " +
        $"Period={payment.Period.ToShortDateString()}, " +
        $"Price={payment.Price}");
}
```

EF6 generates correct SQL:

```sql
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
    [Extent1].[PaymentId] AS [PaymentId], 
    [Extent1].[CustomerId] AS [CustomerId], 
    [Extent1].[Period] AS [Period], 
    [Extent1].[Price] AS [Price]
    FROM [dbo].[Payment] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[Period] < @p__linq__0) AND ([Extent1].[Price] <= @p__linq__1)',
       N'@p__linq__0 datetime2(7),@p__linq__1 int',
       @p__linq__0='2020-10-03 00:00:00',
       @p__linq__1=200
```

However, if I use `Func` lambda with the same condition:

```cs
// Option 2: Func<T, T> lambda
Func<Payment, bool> func = p => p.Period < period;
var payments2 = db.Payments.Where(func).Where(p => p.Price <= price);
```

I don't get the same SQL, but get this one:

```sql
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[PaymentId] AS [PaymentId], 
    [Extent1].[CustomerId] AS [CustomerId], 
    [Extent1].[Period] AS [Period], 
    [Extent1].[Price] AS [Price]
    FROM [dbo].[Payment] AS [Extent1]
```

As far as I understand, EF switched to client-side evaluation. I wonder, why this happened? I'm using same lambda for filtering!

Comment: Expression<Func<Payment, bool>> not just Func. EF needs an Expression to work out the names etc. Funcs are opaque to it so will be run after the whole result set is consumed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an **Expression**, not just a **Func** so EF can work out the names of the properties etc.

Try:

```
Expression<Func<Payment, bool>> func = p => p.Period < period;
```

Comment: Thanks! Now all is OK! Completely forgot about this moment. 